# Automatically re-tweet everything a certain Twitter account has?

Tags: twitter

I don’t want to post tweets like “RT @-other-account-: original-tweet”; I want to use the Twitter native retweet function. (The differences include that people can block the retweeted account; that the retweeted account’s avatar is shown; and that I don’t waste characters with the “RT @-user-:” prefix.)

Is there any way to do this? It would be cool throwing a little app up on a VPS if necessary, but surely there is a service that can provide this already? I know a guy who does this on Twitter

Comment: that would be a violation of twitter's terms

Comment: I mean, thats true but I know a guy whom on Twitter already has this... He even shared me the source code!

Comment: I was referring to why there's no service which does this. Zapier used to support this earlier to my knowledge. Easier for twitter to shutdown a service which mass does this than a random person..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don’t think there’s a way to do this. The best way to do this would just be to turn on notifications and retweet it yourself.